# Facing error in c++ code

Tags: c++

I am writing code of ACM problem in which we have to check possibilities of different items. It's some minor error in the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void CheckPossibilities( int numItems, int maxWeights )
{
    if( numItems <= 0  )
    {
        cout << "Invalid Items";

    }

    if ( maxWeights <= 0 )
    {
        cout << "Impossible";

    }

    while( maxWeights > 0 )
    {
        if(numItems%2==0)                //for even
        {
        numItems = numItems / 2;
        maxWeights--;
        }
        else 
        {
             numItems = (numItems -1)/ 2;      //for odd
             maxWeights--;
        }

    }

    if( numItems <= 1 )
    {
        cout << "Possible";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Impossible";
    }

}

void main()
{

    int  numItems1,maxWeights1;
    cout<<"enter numItems"<<endl;
    cin>>numItems1;
    cout<<"maxWeights"<<endl;
    cin>>maxWeights1;
    cout<<numItems1 "AND" maxWeights1<<endl;
cout<<CheckPossibilities(numItems1, maxWeights1);
}
```

Comment: "Impossible" (pun intended)

Comment: what? sorry i didn't got u

Comment: *All code logic is correct. it's some minor error in the code* either all the logic is correct *or* there is an error in the code. You can't have both.

Comment: What's the problem? what happens? What do you EXPECT to happen?

Comment: Do you know where the error occurs?

Comment: Is it a compiler error or run-time error? And specify what the error is exactly.

Comment: Oh, and you need to understand how integer divide works...

Comment: `cout<<CheckPossibilities(numItems1, maxWeights1);` What do you expect here? `void CheckPossibilities(...`.

Comment: Do you want your function to continue executing if `numItems <= 0`?  The `while` statement will execute regardless of the values of `numItems` or `maxWeights`.  Maybe you need to invest in an `else` clause or a `return` statement.

Comment: You should "factor out" the `maxWeights--` statement since it's in both the `if - true` and `if - false` clauses.  Write it once at the top or bottom of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistakes were trying to cout multiple strings in one line without concatting them in some way, either seperate with a << or a +. You also cant cout a void function because it tries to output void, you just need to call it and let the function do the outputting. With errors fixed the main should be

```
int main()
{

    int  numItems1,maxWeights1;
    cout<<"enter numItems"<<endl;
    cin>>numItems1;
    cout<<"maxWeights"<<endl;
    cin>>maxWeights1;
    cout<<numItems1+"AND"+maxWeights1<<endl;
    CheckPossibilities(numItems1, maxWeights1);
    return 0;
}
```

Next time look at what line the error is thrown on when compiling and search those specific error because these were really simple and specific syntax errors that could be found by a google search easily.

Comment: Thanks man it working

Answer (score -3):

```
void main()
{

  int  numItems1, maxWeights1;
  cout << "enter numItems" << endl;
  cin >> numItems1;
  cout << "maxWeights" << endl;
  cin >> maxWeights1;
  cout << numItems1 <<  "AND" << maxWeights1 << endl;
  CheckPossibilities(numItems1, maxWeights1);
}
```

you can never do this: `cout<<CheckPossibilities(numItems1, maxWeights1);` cout take standard output stream, not functions. And also you forgot to put << in `cout << numItems1 <<  "AND" << maxWeights1 << endl;` in this form, your code build succesful.

Comment: This answer is misleading, the problem isn't that cout *doesn't take functions*, the problem is that the function's return value is void. And obviously printing void doesn't make much sense. Had the function returned an int or a std::string that statement would have been correct.

Comment: Really, `void main()`?  If you are going to show what a "main should look like", at least get the signature correct.